# Auto-completion for latex doesn't work in Latexila and Geany [ubuntu 15.10]

Tags: 15.04, latex, auto-completion

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10. I noticed that auto-completion doesn't work anymore on Latexila so I tried to use Geany with Latex plugin but the result is the same.

I had a quick look on the Internet and I've found a post (https://github.com/Evpok/latex-autocomplete/issues/1) of a guy with a similar issue but nothing more.

I'm currently using Gtk.

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try to use TexStudio? In my opinion it's the best Tex Editor on the planet.

Comment: I gave it a try, same problem. In TexStudio I checked  the completion files and it's currently using latex-document.cwl and latex-mathsymbol.cwl. 
I still get no autocompletion